# HDFStore select_as_multiple generator

Tags: python, pandas, generator, hdf5

**Question:** How can I create a generator that allows for iteration over multiple columns in a pandas HDFStore object?

I am trying to create a wrapper class for a pandas HDFStore object. One of the features I am trying to implement is the ability to iterate over groups of columns in the HDFStore by a given chunksize.  Many machine learning algorithms can operate `on-line` and don't need all of the data at once.

My first attempt was to create a generator function and pass start and stop arguments to the select method of the HDFStore:

```
def iterate(self, key, chunksize=50000):
    node = self.store.get_node(key)
    nrows = node.table.nrows
    current = 0
    while current < nrows:
        yield self.store.select(key, start=current, stop=current+chunksize)
        current += chunksize
```

This works fine, and I am able to iterate over a *single* stored column in the store.  Note, that for testing I am storing every column in its own table.

My next step was to extend this concept to multiple columns from multiple tables using `HDFStore.select_as_multiple`.  While not in the docstring, `select_as_multiple` appears to accept the start and stop arguments as well:

```
>>> store.select_as_multiple(keys='MachineID', start=0, stop=50000)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 50000 entries, 0 to 49999
Data columns:
MachineID    50000  non-null values
dtypes: int64(1)
```

Only 50,000 rows were returned, as requested.  However, when I pass more than 1 key/column the method pulls back ALL of the rows:

```
>>> store.select_as_multiple(keys=['MachineID','YearMade'], start=0, stop=50000)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 401125 entries, 0 to 1124
Data columns:
MachineID    401125  non-null values
YearMade     401125  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2)
```

Is it possible to use `select_as_multiple` to pull back a specified range of rows instead of ALL rows?

**Version info:**

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.10.1'

>>> tables.__version__
'2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because not passing start/stop to the underlying select. Pretty easy fix.

Also been meaning to add iterator support, going to steal your function :)

done
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3078

There are docs, but essentially:

```
for df in store.select('df',chunksize=10000):
    print df
```

Comment: Wooo!  My first contribution to this awesome project.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: done, see the above link for the PR, pls give a try and let me know how this work. this is not yet merged, but will be soon